# Retrieve all words that have a minimum frequency of 5

Tags: python, nltk

I want to retrieve all words that have a minimum frequency of 5 with NLTK and store them in the variable for future processing. Can not find anything in NLTK book. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am using this code and want to filter out words that do not appear more than 5 times.

```
import os
import glob
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def create():
    read_files = glob.glob("D:\\test\\text\\*.txt")
    with open("D:\\test\\temp.txt", "wb") as outfile:
        for f in read_files:
            with open(f, "rb") as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())    

def modify():
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\w']+")
    english_stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    f = open('D:\\test\\temp.txt')
    out = open('D:\\test\\result.txt', 'w')
    raw = f.read()
    a = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
    a = [word.lower() for word in a if word not in english_stops]
    a = list(set(a))
    print(a, file=out)

def remove():
    os.remove("D:\\test\\temp.txt")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create()
    modify()
    remove()
```

Comment: Not everything is described in books.  Try writing some code.

Comment: I am trying, but a little help would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function `FreqDist` to get frequencies that filter them by your creteria:

> A frequency distribution for the outcomes of an experiment.  A
>       frequency distribution records the number of times each outcome of
>       an experiment has occurred.  For example, a frequency distribution
>       could be used to record the frequency of each word type in a
>       document.
>
> [ref](http://jazzparser.granroth-wilding.co.uk/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html)

Here is an example how to use it:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> sentence='''This is my sentence is heloo is heloo my my my my'''
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> fdist=FreqDist(tokens)
```

With this last, we got a list of words with their frequencies, now you should filter them by your conditions `f(w) >= 5`, use the `filter` function:

> **filter(function, iterable)**
>
> Construct an iterator from those elements
>   of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a
>   sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator.
>
> [ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[1]>=5,fdist.items()))
[('my', 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If NLTK is not to be used you can use `collections`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = "This is my sentence is heloo is heloo my my my my"
>>> c = Counter(a.split(" "))
>>> [key for key in c.keys() if c.get(key) == 5]
['my']
```

Comment: I am working with NLTK, so it is must :(